# Getting posts undefined in headless wp with graphQl Next.js

Tags: wordpress, next.js, graphql, undefined, headless

The graphQL query is working [http://trialtest1.local/graphql?query={%20posts%20{%20nodes%20{%20slug%20title%20}%20}}](http://trialtest1.local/graphql?query=%7B%20posts%20%7B%20nodes%20%7B%20slug%20title%20%7D%20%7D%7D)

[image: The h1 shows but not the posts]

But when I ask for posts in next.js it shows undefined. Can anyone see what Im doing wrong?

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function Home( {posts}){
console.log({posts})
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Hello From The Home Page!</h1>
      {
        posts?.nodes?.map(post => {
          return(
            <ul key={post.slug}>
              <li>
                <Link href={`/posts/${post.slug}`}>{post.title}</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )

}

export async function getInitialProps(){

  const res = await fetch('http://trialtest1.local/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `
          query HomePageQuery {
            posts {
              nodes {
                slug
                title
              }
            }
          }
          `,
      })
  })

  const json = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
        posts: json.data.posts,
    },
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Next.js application, the issue might be related to how you're accessing the GraphQL response data. When using '**getInitialProps**', the GraphQL response is usually in the '**data**' object. Here's a modification to your code to access the posts correctly:

```
export async function getInitialProps() {
  const res = await fetch('http://trialtest1.local/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
        query HomePageQuery {
          posts {
            nodes {
              slug
              title
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    }),
  });

  const json = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts: json.data.posts.nodes, // Access nodes directly
    },
  };
}
```

In your component, '**posts**' should now contain an array of post objects. Ensure that you're accessing the correct data structure in the '**Home**' component using '**posts.nodes.map**' to iterate over each post. Also, check your console logs to ensure the data is being fetched and passed correctly to the component.